# Order of elements in $\Bbb Z_8\oplus \Bbb Z_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Does anyone know a quick way other than direct calculations to find the number of the elements in $\Bbb Z_8\times \Bbb Z_8$ of a particular order?

Comment: The can only be 1,2,4,8 and all of them occur, don't they?

Comment: The order of $(x, y) \in G \oplus H$ is the least common multiple of the order of $x \in G$ and the order of $y \in H$.

Comment: Well, if p = a x b and then |p| = least common multiple of |a| and |b|.  As for what is the order of |a| in Z_8... Well, if we are using the notation of 0.... n-1 and we are viewing it as an additive group, for a in Z_n, |a| = n/gcd(a,n).  I think.

Comment: Yes the orders can be 1, 2, 4, 8.  All of them do occur, and yes the order of a pair is the lcm of the orders of each element in the pair.  I am wanting to know how to count them if it can be done easily without direct calculations.

Comment: Quick typing.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that given $(a,b)\in G\times H$ the order of the element is given by $\text{lcm}(o(a), o(b))$. So since all the orders are in $\{1, 2, 4, 8\}$ the lcm is just the max of the two.

So to count we just count based on the number of elements of a given order, of which we know there are four elements of order $8$, two of $4$, one of order $2$, and one of order $1$. So there are $4\cdot 4$ elements of order $8$ where the first coordinate has order $8$ and the second is has order less than $8$, another $4\cdot 4$ where the opposite is true and another $4\cdot 4$ when they both have order $8$ for a total of $48$ elements of order $8$. Next we count where one of the coordinates has order at most $4$ giving $2\cdot 2$ where the first coordinate has order $4$ and the second has order less, another $2\cdot 2$ when the second has the highest order, and then $2\cdot 2$ where they both have order $4$ for a total of $12$ elements of order $4$. Continuing we get three elements of order $2$ and one of order $1$ as usual.

> $$\begin{cases}\#\{x: o(x) = 8 \} = 48 \\
> \#\{x: o(x) = 4 \} = 12 \\
> \# \{x: o(x) = 2\} = 3 \\
> \#\{x: o(x)=1\}=1\end{cases}$$